# event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 charCode is deprecated now

Tags: javascript

event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 charCode is deprecated now, does anyone knows how to replace this

Comment: `event.keyCode` will work.

Comment: keyCode is deprecated also

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code